# How can I avoid updating all instances of my function component with the useState hook in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, instance, react-component

TL;DR I am making a reusable `Button` function component. My `useState()` hook for the button label is updating every `Button` instance. How can I prevent this?

I am very new to React and building a Book Finder app in order to learn. So far my app has a `BookList` and a `ReadingList`. Each `BookDetail` in either list has a `Button` to add/remove that book from the `ReadingList`. The add/remove function works (phew), but using `useState` to update the `Button`'s label updates every instance of the `Button` component, and not just the one that was clicked.

`Buttons` on books in the `BookList` start with label 'Add to Reading List', but if I click **any** of them, **all** of them update to 'Remove from Reading List'.

I've tried moving the logic around into the `Button` component or either `List` component but I just end up breaking the function.

App.js

```
function App() {

const books = useState([])
const [booksToRead, setBooksToRead] = useState([])
const [addRemove, setAddRemove] = useState(true)
const [label, setLabel] = useState('Add to Reading List')

function handleAddBook(book) {
    const newID = book.title_id
    if( (typeof booksToRead.find(x => x.title_id === newID)) == 'undefined' ) {
        setBooksToRead([...booksToRead, book])  
    }
}

function handleRemoveBook(book) {
    console.log(book)
    const array = booksToRead
    const index = array.indexOf(book)
    const newArray = [...array.slice(0, index), ...array.slice(index +1)]
    setBooksToRead(newArray)
}

function addOrRemove(book) {
    if( addRemove ) {
        handleAddBook(book)
        setLabel('Remove from Reading List')
        setAddRemove(false)
    } else {
        handleRemoveBook(book)
        setLabel('Add to Reading List')
        setAddRemove(true)
    }
}

return (
    <main>
        <BookList books={books} handleAddBook={handleAddBook} addOrRemove={addOrRemove} label={label} />
        <ReadingList booksToRead={booksToRead} handleRemoveBook={handleRemoveBook} />
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

BookList.js

```
function BookList ({ book, label, handleAddBook, addOrRemove }) {

    return (
        <div className="booklist">
            {BookData.map((book, index) => {

                const onAddBook = () => addOrRemove(book)

                return (
                <div key={index} className="card">
                    <BookDetail key={book.title_id} book={book} />
                    <Button key={index + 'btn'} label={label} onClick={onAddBook} />
                </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default BookList
```

And finally, Button.js

```
export default function Button({ styleClass, label, onClick }) {

    return (
        <button className='btn' onClick={(event) => onClick(event)}>
            {label}
        </button>
    )
}
```

Unstyled example in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-rgb-fksrp

Answer (score 0):

Can you make these changes and let me know if there any progress:

1. `<Button label={label} onClick={() => addOrRemove(book)} />`
2. `<button className='btn' onClick={onClick}>`

It looks like that in `button` you are passing `event` instead of `book` as function parameter

Comment: function still works, but each instance of Button is still updating :/

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense. Let move `Button` component inside `BookDetail` component. Also add `onClick` prop to `BookDetail` component. Let me know if you are making progress. N.B. remove `Button` from the `BookList` component

Comment: Okay, now the function still works but the label does not change. Progress?!

Comment: Can you also add `console.log(index)` just below `const index = array.indexOf(book)`. I am not sure that you are getting indexes properly

Comment: the index is correct, the function always adds the right book into the `ReadingList`

Comment: That is good. Can you create a simpe example on https://codesandbox.io/ (you can ommit styles) so I can try to debbug it. Will be online for the next 30 or so. Just let me know if you can't so I can go to bed :)

Comment: Here is much simplified, working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-stallman-xsu0u. How I see the problem with an examle you've posted is hard to track and sync state. All books were not stored in state but in JSON file (which uses `BookList` component). Than you have another list for `ReadingList` component. Having single books list reduces surface error for bugs. All I am doing in provided example is toggling `inReadList` attribute on selected book. So less data to handle, less state to manage less helper functions to maintain

Comment: Incredible  and so simple! Thank you! Shows me I should think more before coding away. This definitely solves the problem, but it doesn't exactly answer the question .. not sure what to do about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210345/discussion-between-fastasleep-and-danko).

Answer (score 0):

As it is right now, you are declaring a single label and using that same one on all your book entries. This is why they all display the same label. You would need to keep track of the label of each book, for instance by keeping the label as a field in the book object.

For example:

```
const books = useState([{ label: 'Add to reading list', addRemove: true }])
```

And then:

```
function addOrRemove(book) {
    if( book.addRemove ) {
        handleAddBook(book)
        book.label = 'Remove from Reading List'
        book.addOrRemove = false
    } else {
        handleRemoveBook(book)
        book.label = 'Add to Reading List'
        book.addOrRemove = true
    }
}
```

This way, each book has it's own label.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I think you meant `book.addRemove` in the if/else. I tried your suggestion but now the labels don't change at all and the function doesn't work.